# Running an SSL enabled Azure website locally

Tags: ssl, azure

I have SSL working fine in production but have some issues locally.

When I run the site it opens 2 tabs, one http:// and one https://

I want to just use the http:// tab locally for testing. When I go to a page that requires https I get the error:

> Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a
>   problem with the server or it may be requiring a client authentication
>   certificate that you don't have

I have added the certificate to:

Persona/Certificates
Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates
Intermediate Certification Authorities/Certificates

Everything works fine locally when I use the https:// tab.

Do I need to add the certificate somewhere else too?

Answer (score 0):

Using SSL certs locally is always a challenge.  When the website opens, it's likely using the loopback IP (127.0.0.1) which will always (rare exceptions, perhaps, that I can't think of) give a certificate error, because the cert is bound to a domain name, not an IP.  Ideally you'd probably want to not use your websites real SSL cert locally anyway for security reasons.

You can use a self signed cert for localhost, which should work:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/32bc5a61-1f7b-4545-a514-a11652f11200

Also, I just blogged a code snippet we've used before -- in short, it just avoids using SSL for local connections and otherwise lets you define which pages/folders should otherwise be SSL protected...
http://www.structuretoobig.com/post/2013/02/19/Skipping-SSL-Connections-Locally.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I just tried adding a self signed cert and rebooting just in case but still no luck. I'll carry on testing with the https:// tab that works and come back to this later as it's not too important.